# Chai - Should have Property - Supertest

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

Trying to check for an existence of a property and that it's not an empty string.

I can get this test to work fine:

```
it('the data includes a list of items', function(done){
    body.should.have.property('items').and.to.be.an('array');
    done();
});
```

But below, when I try to check the properties existing in the item array, I can't get it to work:

```
it('each item should include properties \'label\' and \'url\'', function(done){
    body['items'].should.have.property('label').and.to.be.a('string');
    body['items'].should.have.property('url').and.to.be.a('string');
    done();
});
```

but I get the error AssertionError: `expected [ Array(3) ] to have a property 'label'`

The JSON object coming back looks like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "label": "Item 1",
      "url": "http://www.something.com"
    },
    {
      "label": "Item 2",
      "url": "http://www.something.com"
    },
    {
      "label": "Item 3",
      "url": "http://www.something.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this one:

```
    it('each item should include properties \'label\' and \'url\'', function(done){ 
        var firstItem = body.items[0];
        firstItem.should.have.property('label').and.to.be.a('string');
        firstItem.should.have.property('url').and.to.be.a('string');
        done();
            });
```

Comment: thanks man, it takes a bit of work to get to know how to use chai and all the other middleware together.  There's no definitive example list or list of official you can do xyz...unless I'm just not looking at the right projects and wrapper around these other projects in github nightmare..